# Eliminar elementos de un array en jquery

Tags: jquery

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla que se va llenando con varios array que al darle click en un botón se trasladan los valores hacia otra tabla, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es cuando quiero quitar los valores (hay un botón en cada fila de la tabla) al darle click a un valor puedo eliminar, pero si hay 3 elementos y elimino el primero, la tabla se queda con un ancho (length) de 0 es como si eliminara todos los registros siguientes, así si elimino el 2do registro se eliminan los siguientes, les dejo parte del código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var cont=0;
        var total=0;
        var arr_canti=[];
        var arr_id_bodega_producto=[];
        var arr_precio = [];
        var arr_subtotal = [];
        var v_id_bodega_producto = 0; 
        var v_producto =  "";
        var v_existencia = 0;
        var v_pre1 = 0;
        var v_pre2 = 0;
        var v_pre3 = 0;
        var v_pre4 = 0;
        var v_pre0 = 0;
        var v_canti = 0;
        var v_precio = 0;
        var v_id_del = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.agregar_fila').click(function(){
            document.getElementById('caja3').style.display='block';

            v_id_bodega_producto = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_id_bodega_producto').attr('value'); 
            v_producto =  $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_producto').attr('value');
            v_existencia = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_existencia').attr('value'));
            v_pre1 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_pre1').attr('value');
            v_pre2 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_pre2').attr('value');
            v_pre3 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_pre3').attr('value');
            v_pre4 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_pre4').attr('value');
            v_pre0 = $(this).parent().parent().find('input#val_pre_farm').attr('value');


            $('#pre_producto').val(v_producto);
            $('#pre_existencia').val(v_existencia);
            $('#desc1').html(v_pre1);
            $('#desc2').html(v_pre2);
            $('#desc3').html(v_pre3);
            $('#desc4').html(v_pre4);
            $('#desc0').html(v_pre0);

            $('#des0').val(v_pre0);
            $('#des1').val(v_pre1);
            $('#des2').val(v_pre2);
            $('#des3').val(v_pre3);
            $('#des4').val(v_pre4);
        });
    });
    function quitar(){
        v_id_del = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text();
        /*arr_canti.splice(v_id_del,1);
        arr_precio.splice(v_id_del,1);
        arr_id_bodega_producto.splice(v_id_del,1);
        arr_subtotal.splice(v_id_del,1);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();*/
        //$(this).parent().parent().empty();
        alert("el id es "+v_id_del);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.quitar_fila').click(function(){
            alert("hizo click");
            //quitar();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_agr').click(function(){
            agregar();
        });
    });
    function agregar(){
        v_canti = $('#canti').val();
            v_precio = $("input[name='descuento']:checked").val();
            //alert("los valores son v_canti: "+v_canti+" id: "+v_id_bodega_producto+" v_precio: "+v_precio+" contador  "+cont+" v_existencia "+v_existencia+" total "+total);
            if(v_canti>0 && v_canti<=v_existencia)
            {

                arr_canti.push(v_canti);    
                arr_precio.push(v_precio);
                arr_id_bodega_producto.push(v_id_bodega_producto);
                arr_subtotal.push(arr_canti[cont]*arr_precio[cont]);
                total+=arr_subtotal[cont];
                var fila = '<tr id="no_fila'+cont+'" name="filas[]" "><td style="display:none;">'+cont+'</td><td>'+arr_canti[cont]+'</td><td>'+v_producto+'</td><td>'+arr_subtotal[cont]+'</td><td><a href="#" class="quitar_fila"><i class="fas fa-minus-square" style="font-size:50px; color: #c23235;"></i></a></td></tr>';
                $('#articulo3').append(fila);
                cont++;
                document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;
                $('#caja3').hide();
            }
            else{
                alert("Cantidad Invalida");
            }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_bor').click(function(){
            $('#caja3').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Gracias por los comentarios, tal vez para mas explicacion, no quiero solo borrar el valor, los valores los almaceno en un array y luego los muestro en inputs (esto es opcional pero si los quiero en una tabla) entonces aparte de quitar el valor en el array, necesito quitar su respectiva fila (con todo y td)

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que quieres entonces, eliminar qué y cuándo? Como observación, en tu página debes eliminar todos los `$(document).ready(function(){` de más, basta con que tengas uno, y dentro de él todas las funciones que dependen directamente del DOM.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas quitando toda la etiqueta `<td>Datos</td>`.

 Si tienes una tabla 3x3 y eliminas una de las celas la tabla pierde su estructura. 
Para vacial dicha celda basta con que le vacies el valor:

```
//Con esto vacias completamente la celda
$(this).html("");

//Con este estableces el 0 como dato de la celda
$(this).html("0");
```

De esta forma no eliminas la celda sino solo su valor

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Vacia la columna
  $("tr:nth-child(1)>td").click(function(){
      $(this).html("");
  });
  // Establece el valor a 0
  $("tr:nth-child(2)>td").click(function(){
      $(this).html("0");
  });
  // Escribe vacio
  $("tr:nth-child(3)>td").click(function(){
      $(this).html("vaciado");
  });
});
```

```css
table,tr,td{
   border:1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   cursor:pointer;
}
td{
   padding:5px;
   width:60px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
        <td>Dato</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

no se como es exactamente tu estructura, pero te dejo un ejemplo de como podes remover el valor del array y su respectiva fila.

```js
var array = [
    ["1","dato numero 1"],
    ["2","dato numero 2"],
    ["3","dato numero 3"],
    ["4","dato numero 4"],
    ["5","dato numero 5"],
    ["6","dato numero 6"],
    ["7", "dato numero 7"],
    ["8", "dato numero 8"],
    ["9", "dato numero 9"]
];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  $("#tabla").append("<tr><td>"+ array[i][0]+"</td><td>"+ array[i][1]+"</td><td><button type='button' onclick='remove(event)'>remover</button></td></tr>");
}

function remove(e) {
  var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
  if( $(tr).index() >= 0) {
      array.splice($(tr).index(),1);
  }
  $(tr).remove();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
</table>
```

cuando agregas tus tablas dinamicamente, agrega un boton que tenga el atributo `onclick`, y que llame la función `remove()` y le pase como argumento `event` : `<button type="button" onclick="remove(event)">borrar</button>`

en la función `remove()` que es la que nos interesa hacemos lo siguiente :

1. tomamos el row del elemento gracias a la función de jQuery `.closest()` que lo que hace es buscar el nombre del tag mas cercano que recive como argumento, en este caso le pasamos `TR` y nos lleva directamente hacia su padre.
2. tomamos el indice de la row que obtuvimos en el paso anterior gracias a la función `.index()`
3. si el indice es mayor a 0, utilizamos el metodo `splice` diciendole que elimine el el elemento que se encuentra en el indice y como segundo argumento le decimos que elimine solo 1 elemento, entonces nos quedaria asi `array.splice(indice,1)`
4. ahora nos falta solo remover la linea completa, es decir nuestro `tr`, visto que en el paso numero 1 guardamos el elemento en la variable tr, utilizamos la función `.remove()` y nos quedaria `$(tr).remove()`

espero que pueda ser de ayuda a alguien